# I'm getting a FileNotFoundException while trying to httpcon.getInputStream(). Is there a way to easily check if it's a 404 webpage?

Tags: java, exception, html, filenotfoundexception

So in part of my code I'm trying to access a web page, and in the circumstance that the webpage doesn't exist (which I'm testing) I get a FileNotFoundException.

*at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)*

*at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)*

I really just want to be able to check if it doesn't exists, and if it doesn't I wouldn't bother with the getInputStream or BufferedReader or whatever. Is there a simple IF clause that would satisfy this?

```
oracle = new URL(scholarURL);   

HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) oracle.openConnection(); 
httpcon.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76"); 

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpcon.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: Consider using a better Java http client. Apache's is a good one.

Answer (score 3):

Before getting the `InputStream`, simply retrieve the status code.

```
if (con.getResponseCode() == 404) {
    // do something
    InputStream err = con.getErrorStream();
    // use it
}
```

Note how you should be using `UrlConnection#getErrorStream()` in case of an error (well non-2xx status code).

Also, seriously consider using a different, better HTTP client. I suggest [Apache's HttpComponents.](http://hc.apache.org/)